# JS custom scrollbar thumb sizing problems relative to element scrollwidth

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I made a custom scrollbar for a component.

I calculate length of its thumb by `viewportWidth / element.scrollWidth;` It gives me the value in % that I then apply to the thumb element.

But for some reason, after viewportWidth becomes a certain amount(622px wide in my case, and I don't know what this number means or does such that scrollbar breaks, content is a bunch of boxes, each box is 350px wide and has 1rem(16px) wide margins on both sides, thus each box takes around 382 pixels if that matters) scrollbar becomes longer than it should be, and in order to scroll content all the way left, you need to move thumb out of scrollbar length.

Here is my code:

```js
  const clamp = (val, min, max) => {
    return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
  }

class ScrollableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { holding: false, xLocation: 0, width: 0 };
  lastPos = 0;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollbarRef = React.createRef();
    this.scrollContentRef = React.createRef();
  }

  correction = 0;

  scroll = amount => {
    this.setState({
      xLocation: clamp(
        this.state.xLocation + amount,
        0,
        this.getFullWidth() - this.getAbsoluteThumbWidth() - this.correction
      )
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      if (this.state.holding) {
        let delta = e.pageX - this.lastPos;
        this.scroll(delta);
        this.lastPos = e.pageX;
      }
    });
    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      this.setState({ holding: false });
    });
  };

  getFullWidth = () => {
    return this.scrollbarRef.current
      ? this.scrollbarRef.current.clientWidth
      : this.default;
  };
  contentScrollWidth = () => {
    if (this.scrollContentRef.current) {
      return this.scrollContentRef.current.scrollWidth;
    }
  };
  contentViewportWidth = () => {
    if (this.scrollContentRef.current) {
      return this.scrollContentRef.current.clientWidth;
    }
  };

  getRelativeThumbWidth = () => {
    // console.log(this.getFullWidth(), this.contentScrollWidth());
    return this.getFullWidth() / this.contentScrollWidth();
  };

  getAbsoluteThumbWidth = () => {
    return this.getRelativeThumbWidth() * this.getFullWidth();
  };

  default = 100;
  render() {
    let calcedWidth = this.getRelativeThumbWidth();
    let thumbPosition =
      this.state.xLocation /
      (this.getFullWidth() - this.getAbsoluteThumbWidth() - this.correction);

    console.log(thumbPosition);

    let scrollAmount =
      thumbPosition * (this.contentScrollWidth() - this.contentViewportWidth());

    // console.log(thumbPosition, scrollAmount);

    if (this.scrollContentRef.current) {
      this.scrollContentRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollAmount;
    }
    return (
      <div
        {...this.props}
        onWheel={e => {
          this.scroll(e.deltaY);
        }}
        onTouchMove={e => {
          let newX = e.touches[0].clientX;
          this.scroll(newX - this.lastPos);
          this.lastPos = newX;
        }}
      >
        <div ref={this.scrollContentRef} className="overflow-hidden">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <div className={"scrollbar" + " mt-auto"} ref={this.scrollbarRef}>
          <span
            style={{
              transform: `translateX(${this.state.xLocation}px)`,
              width: calcedWidth * 100 + "%"
            }}
            onMouseDown={e => {
              this.lastPos = e.clientX;
              this.setState({ holding: true });
            }}
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PreviewBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "bg-black mx-4 w-350px h-48 flex-shrink-0 inline-block align-top " +
          "previewBox"
        }
      ></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <ScrollableComponent
                    className={
                      "transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out my-auto flex flex-col w-full px-8 "
                    }
                  >
                    <div className="inline-block whitespace-no-wrap mb-4 py-8 ">
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                    </div>
                  </ScrollableComponent>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.scrollbar {
  user-select: none;
  touch-action: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 25px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  // padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  span {
    min-width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #b94747;
  }
  span:hover {
      background: #ff6060;
    }
.previewBox {
width:350px;
background:black;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .previewBox:hover {
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
    transform: scale(1.025);
  }
```

```html
<div id = "root"></div>
<p class="px-8 mt-3">If you make your screen wider, you'll see that scrollbar works OK, if its not wide enough, its thumb will have to go out of viewport to work</p>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it's confusing, since `scrollWidth` stays the same no matter the screen size, thus we know that `scrollWidth` is definitely correct.

Variable here is `viewportWidth`, it changes, but so far, as I think, it changes correctly too.

`state.xLocation` just can not be wrong even theoretically, its just a number that you can increase as much as you want.

`this.getFullWidth()` gives correct value.

Hence, thumb size is correct. Problem lays in `thumbPosition`, but here is a catch, How does this happen if formula for `thumbPosition` uses all correct values?!

(`this.getAbsoluteThumbWidth()` is just relative width in fractions, multiplied by `viewportWidth`)

I am sincerely confused by my creation.

Comment: Do you mean that when you resize the window the thumbs are not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const clamp = (val, min, max) => {
    return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
  }

class ScrollableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { holding: false, xLocation: 0, width: 0 };
  lastPos = 0;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollbarRef = React.createRef();
    this.scrollContentRef = React.createRef();
  }

  correction = 0;

  scroll = amount => {
    this.setState({
      xLocation: clamp(
        this.state.xLocation + amount,
        0,
        this.getFullWidth() - this.getAbsoluteThumbWidth() - this.correction
      )
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      if (this.state.holding) {
        let delta = e.pageX - this.lastPos;
        this.scroll(delta);
        this.lastPos = e.pageX;
      }
    });
    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      this.setState({ holding: false });
    });
  };

  getFullWidth = () => {
    return this.scrollbarRef.current
      ? this.scrollbarRef.current.clientWidth
      : this.default;
  };
  contentScrollWidth = () => {
    if (this.scrollContentRef.current) {
      return this.scrollContentRef.current.scrollWidth;
    }
  };
  contentViewportWidth = () => {
    if (this.scrollContentRef.current) {
      return this.scrollContentRef.current.clientWidth;
    }
  };

  getRelativeThumbWidth = () => {
    // console.log(this.getFullWidth(), this.contentScrollWidth());
    return this.getFullWidth() / this.contentScrollWidth();
  };

  getAbsoluteThumbWidth = () => {
    return this.getRelativeThumbWidth() * this.getFullWidth();
  };

  default = 100;
  render() {
    let calcedWidth = this.getRelativeThumbWidth();
    let thumbPosition =
      this.state.xLocation /
      (this.getFullWidth() - this.getAbsoluteThumbWidth() - this.correction);

    console.log(thumbPosition);

    let scrollAmount =
      thumbPosition * (this.contentScrollWidth() - this.contentViewportWidth());

    // console.log(thumbPosition, scrollAmount);

    if (this.scrollContentRef.current) {
      this.scrollContentRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollAmount;
    }
    return (
      <div
        {...this.props}
        onWheel={e => {
          this.scroll(e.deltaY);
        }}
        onTouchMove={e => {
          let newX = e.touches[0].clientX;
          this.scroll(newX - this.lastPos);
          this.lastPos = newX;
        }}
      >
        <div ref={this.scrollContentRef} className="overflow-hidden">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <div className={"scrollbar" + " mt-auto"} ref={this.scrollbarRef}>
          <span
            style={{
              transform: `translateX(${this.state.xLocation}px)`,
              width: calcedWidth * 100 + "%"
            }}
            onMouseDown={e => {
              this.lastPos = e.clientX;
              this.setState({ holding: true });
            }}
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PreviewBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "bg-black mx-4 w-350px h-48 flex-shrink-0 inline-block align-top " +
          "previewBox"
        }
      ></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <ScrollableComponent
                    className={
                      "transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out my-auto flex flex-col w-full px-8 "
                    }
                  >
                    <div className="inline-block whitespace-no-wrap mb-4 py-8 ">
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                      <PreviewBox />
                    </div>
                  </ScrollableComponent>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.scrollbar {
  user-select: none;
  touch-action: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 25px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  // padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  span {
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #b94747;
  }
  span:hover {
      background: #ff6060;
    }
.previewBox {
width:350px;
background:black;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .previewBox:hover {
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
    transform: scale(1.025);
  }
```

```html
<div id = "root"></div>
<p class="px-8 mt-3">If you make your screen wider, you'll see that scrollbar works OK, if its not wide enough, its thumb will have to go out of viewport to work</p>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So here is the problem

```
span {
    min-width: 200px; // this
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #b94747;
}
```

you should change it to `width` so that it can be overwritten you may also want to update the width in `componentDidMount` for the first render

Comment: @Nick for better UX set width to 0 in css and change it in componentDidMount